# Can't use meteor mongo to do operations on collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

As the question states, I can't do "collection name" . find({}) or any operations once I used meteor mongo... please help.

```
Log: 
meteor:PRIMARY> show dbs 
admin   (empty) 
local  0.063GB
meteor  0.031GB 
meteor:PRIMARY> show collections
chats 
meteor_accounts_login
ServiceConfiguration 
profiles 
system.indexes
topics 
users 
meteor:PRIMARY> users.find() 
2015-11-18T08:43:53.240-0800 ReferenceError: users is not defined 
meteor:PRIMARY> Topics.find() 
2015-11-18T08:43:58.472-0800 ReferenceError: Topics is not defined    

meteor:PRIMARY> topics.find()
2015-11-18T08:45:26.494-0800 ReferenceError: topics is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try db.users.find() usually we use to find in mongodb

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/